# Relating NP-Complete problems to real world problems

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I have a decent grasp of NP Complete problems; that's not the issue.  What I don't have is a good sense of where they turn up in "real" programming.  Some (like knapsack and traveling salesman) are obvious, but others don't seem obviously connected to "real" problems.

I've had the experience several times of struggling with a difficult problem only to realize it is a well known NP Complete problem that has been researched extensively.  If I had recognized the connection more quickly I could have saved quite a bit of time researching existing solutions to my specific problem.

Are there any resources (online or print) that specifically connect NP Complete to real world instances?

Edit:
For example, I was working on a program that tried to divide students into groups based on age, grade, and school of origin, which is essentially a graph partitioning problem. It took me a while to realize the connection.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_np_complete_problems

Comment: Last time I looked, wikipedia was a poor source for practical applications.  It seems to have improved somewhat.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I agree that seeing some real-world instances of NP-complete/hard problems, and seeing the connection to the abstract version, would in time increase your intuition for making the connection.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that [Computers and Intractability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716710455) is the definitive reference on this topic.

Comment: Any comments on the extent to which they discuss connections to real world problems? It seems to focus heavily on theory (which is fine, but not what I'm looking for right now).

Comment: They don't discuss real-world problems all that much, but they've got a very impressive array of NP-complete problems, and some discussion on how to prove a problem NP-complete.  Once you think you might be dealing with an NP-complete or NP-hard problem, it's a good book to look through and see if anything looks familiar.

Comment: It's focused on theory.  However, its fairly short and if you read it, it will help you develop that intuition for what is probably NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the connection you are talking about must be extracted with a so-called *reduction*, for example you reduce **3-SAT** to the problem you are working with and then you can conclude that your problem has the same complexity of it.

This passage is not trivial, since you have to prove that you can turn every problem instance **l** of a known *NP-Hard* problem **L** into an instance **c** of your problem **C** using a deterministic polinomyal algorithms.

So, except from learning basical correlations of common *NP-Hard* problems using your memory, there's no way to be sure if a problem is similar to another *NP-Hard* without first trying to guessing and then proving it, you have to be smart.

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but that's not really what I'm talking about.  For example, I was working on a program that tried to divide students into groups based on age, grade, and school of origin, which is essentially a graph partitioning problem.  It took me quite a while to realize that.

Answer (score 1):

here is a wiki link:
http://wapedia.mobi/en/List_of_NP-complete_problems
Notice it says

> This list is in no way comprehensive (there are more than 3000 known NP-complete problems)

probably it would be a great task if anyone could compile such list.

A theorist should try to understand/proof an NP-Complete/Hard problem. But, a programmer doesn't have that time to. He needs a list.

Am I correct?

I think you **should google it**. And, read through all the links. Add *any new problem* found in the link to your list.

Hope it helps

PS : Don't forget to post the list when you're finished :P

Answer (score 0):

For developing better intuition the book "**The Algorithm Design Manual, Second Edition**" by Skiena (excerpts on google books) is simply great.

1. List in the back with problems
   (including hard problems), that
   include an illustration and a
   discussion (often) with a **real world
   example**.
2. Covers both the theoretical
   and practical side of things, often
   talking about actual code.

Read excepts online here (see some examples in chapters 14): 
http://books.google.dk/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Chapter 16 (not online) discusses some hard problems, including graph partition.

Comment: Also, for the hard problems, it gives suggestions as to how you'd actually solve them using e.g. an approximation algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm design manual also mentions a book by Garey and Johnson, which has a list of 400 NP-complete problems with comments. The comments being the good part I think. I don't have this book, but I'm thinking about buying it. Like you, I'd like to get better intuition for recognizing hard problems in the real world :)

He says: Browse through the catalog as soon as you question the existance of an efficient algorithm for your problem. Indeed this is the single book in my library that I reach for most often.